# Dense subspace of dense subspace is dense

Tags: general-topology, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $V$, $W$ to linear subspaces such that $V\subset W\subset H$ with $V$ dense in $W$ and $W$ dense in $H$. Does this implie that $V$ is also dense in $H$? I think you can make an epsilon-estimate to prove this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Let $U\subseteq H$ be open. Then, $U\cap W$ is non-empty and open in $W$. Thus, $\exists  x\in V\cap(U\cap W)$. So $V$ is dense in $H$.

Answer (score 0):

The condition $V$ is dense in $W$ can be written as $\bar{V}\cap W=W$ or, equivalently, $W\subset\bar{V}$. By passing, in this last formula, to the closure we get $H=\bar{W}\subset\bar{\bar{V}}=\bar{V}\subset H$. This forces $\bar{V}=H$, as required.